# PCIM176J panel meter

Tags: meter, panel

I scored a couple of panel meters stamped PCIM 176J.  Anyone have a datasheet for this thing? Google found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably from the 1980s pre-internet era. A quick Google search finds it is a panel meter made by "Printed Circuits International".

Most such digital panel meters of that era were based on the ICL7106 chip and are fairly standardized. You may have better luck simply looking at the connections and figuring it out. There should be power, analog input and some way of actuating the decimal points.